# NiFi Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date

Tags: sql, postgresql, apache-nifi, parseexception

I'm trying to insert a flowfile from NiFi into PostgreSQL database. Flowfile is a JSON which keys are: id, timestamp, metric1, metric2, ..., and I have problems with timestamp data.

This is the value of SQL Insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO egillor.metrics (id, consumo_red, generacion_pv, timestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

And this is the error

```
Unable to execute SQL select query INSERT INTO egillor.metrics (id, consumo_red, generacion_pv, timestamp) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) for StandardFlowFileRecord ... due to 
java.sql.SQLDataException: The value of the sql.args.4.value is '2021-05-22T00:00:00+02:00', which cannot 
be converted to a timestamp; routing to failure:
```

At the middle of the log, I have the following clue, but I don't now how to fix it

```
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2021-05-22T00:00:00+02:00"
```

So, I have to deal with java.text.ParseException from inside a PutDatabaseRecord processor...

Does anyone had this problem in the past? Does anyone know how I can fix it?

Comment: format your date in your insert statement. get rid of ‘+02:00’ section.

Comment: I can't. I mean: I put only a json into the PutDatabaseRecord, and it works with it and insert multiple jsons in an array, so I can't modify the SQL statement. And, I've tried to delete the timezone +02:00, but it doesn't work either. It raises the same error